# Laravel Common Api Routes for Different Authentication Guards

Tags: laravel, api

I have several authentication guards on my app like below:

```
'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'api-customer' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'customers',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'api-manufacturer' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'manufacturers',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
```

I have some common routes for api and api-manufacturer and I created my routes like below

```
Route::middleware('auth:api', 'verified')->group( function () {
    Route::post('bids/job/update-quote', 'BidController@updateOrCreateQuote');
}
Route::middleware('auth:api-manufacturer')->group(function () {
    Route::post('bids/job/update-quote', 'BidController@updateOrCreateQuote');
}
```

in this case only second route definition is working, I mean for api-manufacturer guard. I tried to add both middleware like `middleware(['auth:api, auth:api-manufacturer'])....` but it didn't work also. I think this checks for both auth guards..

How to do that in proper way.. I will need same approach while creating admin user..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `auth` (`Authenticate`) middleware takes a list of possible guards to check. You can pass multiple guards to it and it will spin through them until one of them returns a user.

```
middleware('auth:api,api-manufacturer')
```

If a guard returns a user then it will also set that as the default guard.

Comment: this doesn't work.. gives api-manufacturer didn't defined error..

Comment: gives what error? that guard is defined and this is how the auth middleware works

Comment: this checks for both guards.. it's not suitable for my case.. I need auth:api || auth:api-manufacturer,, not auth:api && auth:api-manufacturer

Comment: and gives "message: "Auth guard [ api-manufacturer] is not defined." that error.. but first one, auth:api, works... maybe this sintax is worn.. by the way I create personal auth token for api-manufacturer guard..

Comment: ok.. my mistake is putting space after comma.. it works now.. thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is checking one of two guards not both, like if one of the guards passed then it pass to the route.

you have two options:

1. First: simplest, create a new route that redirects to the same controller method like:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api', 'verified')->group( function () {
    Route::post('bids/job/update-quote', 'BidController@updateOrCreateQuote');
}
Route::middleware('auth:api-manufacturer')->group(function () {
    Route::post('bids/job/manufacturer/update-quote', 'BidController@updateOrCreateQuote');
}
```

2. Second: add a new middle ware that check if one of the two guard passed, then it pass to route, and implemented to the route:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (!Auth::guard('api')->check() && !Auth::guard('api-manufacturer')->check()) {
        return redirect('/login'); // or any un auth response 
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: second option worked .. thank you. first option is simple but I can't use it because both user group use same vue component at frontend side and send request to same end point.. I  need to take out common routes from routes group while using your first solution, it's ok for non apiResource routes... now I wonder how can I do it when I want to reach a api resource route via both guards?

Comment: I have new problem... your second solution works but I can't reach `Auth::user()->id` or any user info.